# Flutter: Wait for async void method

Tags: android, asynchronous, flutter

I have an async save method that writes to the file system. The return type is void. I want to update the ui as soon as save is finished. Usually I would do that with the then() method, but it's not applicable with a return type of void? So how can I get notified, when save has finished?

```
  void save(Folder folder) async {  
   .....
  }
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Change the return type to `Future<void>`.

```
Future<void> save(Folder folder) async {  
   .....
}
```

Then you can do `await save(...);` or `save().then(...);`

Answer (score -1):

you could use `Future<Null>` instead of void.

```
Future<Null> save(Folder folder) async {  
   .....
  }
```

Comment: After the release of Dart 2, you like want to use `Future<void>`.

https://medium.com/dartlang/future-void-vs-future-null-whats-the-difference-84a42d616e7d